# General mechanism to snap to pixel and avoid blurryness

Tags: javafx, blur

I'm creating a healthbar with 2 rectangles overlapping each other. The inner shows the current health, the outer shows the total health.

**Problem**

The healthbar is blurry.

**What I've got so far**

I've read about e. g. [having to add 0.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846659/how-to-draw-an-1-pixel-line-using-javafx-canvas), but it only solves the problem partially.

A screenshot, top image is without the 0.5, bottom image is with the 0.5 added.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
private class HealthBar extends Pane {

    Rectangle outerHealthRect;
    Rectangle innerHealthRect;

    public HealthBar() {

        double height = 10;

        double outerWidth = 60;
        double innerWidth = 40;

        // using 0.5, otherwise it would be blurry
        double x=snap( 0.0);
        double y=snap( 0.0);

        outerHealthRect = new Rectangle( x, y, outerWidth, height);
        outerHealthRect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        outerHealthRect.setFill(Color.WHITE);

        innerHealthRect = new Rectangle( x, y, innerWidth, height);
        innerHealthRect.setStroke(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        innerHealthRect.setFill(Color.LIMEGREEN);

        getChildren().addAll( outerHealthRect);
        getChildren().addAll( innerHealthRect);

    }

    public void setValue( double value) {
        innerHealthRect.setWidth( snap( outerHealthRect.getWidth() * value));
    }

    private double snap( double value) {
        return (int) value + 0.5;
    }
}
```

After I applied scaling for debug purposes it became obvious that the transparent stroke isn't considered as transparent line of the same width like a stroke with color:

[image]

**Questions**

- Is there an option to snap to pixels, i. e. have sharp pixels in general without having to mess around with 0.5?
- How can I make the transparent stroke the same width as the outer stroke?

I could try a different approach with a canvas, but these are general questions which affect the way you have to set up a JavaFX application.

Thank you very much.

Comment: In case you haven't seen this, http://stackoverflow.com/a/11887786/2855515

Comment: Thank you, I haven't seen it, but when I searched the web I found both the snapToPixels and that you should use INSIDE or OUTSIDE instead of CENTERED. These give me the best results so far. But there's still blurryness after I apply them, e. g. on the right side of the green rectangle is a single line of blur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't snap the fill.  The question I linked to explains that lines are drawn on the pixels(through the middle - which takes a whole pixel), which means +0.5 since the coords are between pixels.

Fills need to be drawn over the whole pixel to the space between them.

[image]

```
public HealthBar() {

    double height = 10;

    double outerWidth = 60;
    double innerWidth = 40;

    double x=10,y=10;//away from pane edge just to see better

    outerHealthRect = new Rectangle( snap(x), snap(y), outerWidth, height);
    outerHealthRect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    outerHealthRect.setFill(Color.WHITE);

    //just move green bar right a bit to see edges
    //and move it down 1 pix so it's not over the black edge
    //this means height is -1 as well
    innerHealthRect = new Rectangle( x+11, y+1, innerWidth, height-1);
    innerHealthRect.setFill(Color.LIMEGREEN);
    //no need to draw transparent anything

    getChildren().addAll( outerHealthRect);
    getChildren().addAll( innerHealthRect);

}
```